# passing a query string through ajax as a string

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, string

I am trying to pass a string through ajax, however the string is a query string taken from a search and looks something like this:

```
search=&site=0&salesperson=0&referral=0&product=0&estimate=0&sort=date&open=on&filter_sbmt=Filter+Prospect&limit=30
```

So when I pass it through ajax as the variable `url=search=&site=0...` it sets the `$_POST['url']="search=",` and then separates &site as a new post, rather than keeping the entire string in one.

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : '//'+base_url+'/ajax2/customer-search.php',
    data    : 'url='+url,
    success : function(data) {
        $('#customers_table').html(data);
    }
});
```

I have tried decoding it with json both on the php side and javascript side. This did not help either. I am out of ideas.

How can I get this string `"search=&site=0&salesperson=0&referral=0&product=0&estimate=0&sort=date&open=on&filter_sbmt=Filter+Prospect&limit=30"` on to ajax/customer-search.php

Comment: `urlencode()/URLencode()/encodeURI()` would be a good place to start

Comment: how do I decode it back?

Comment: Try `urldecode()/URLdecdode/decodeURI()`

Comment: Try passing data as an object: `data: { url: url }`

Comment: Just use `data: url` and then you should be able to access `$_POST['search']`, `$_POST['site']`, `$_POST['salesperson']`, etc

Answer (score 2):

jQuery will encode the data for you if you pass an object and not a string.

```
data    : { url }
```

Alternatively, modern browsers have a URLSearchParams object that will encode the data for you:

```
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
searchParams.append("url", url);
var data = searchParams.toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use parse_str()

```
$params = array();
parse_str($_POST['url'], $params);

print $params["salesperson"];
```

Comment: No, they can't. The `&` in the data (as the question states) means that `salesperson` doesn't appear in `url`.

Comment: use   data    : {url:url}, in ajax
and on ajax/customer-search.php file  print_r($_POST); exit; you will get the url string